# How to touch Android buttons?

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

I have three buttons button a and b , c .I want to touch the three buttons as in the picture.I'm a new education in the Android please help me. thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NyZm.png)

Comment: you want to click all three at a time?

Comment: Is this a swipe operation?

Comment: Yes, I need to touch  button a to button c

Comment: Is this a difficult question?

Answer (score 0):

- create a Layout
- add Views to your Layout
- set the setOnTouchListener to your Layout
- override the onTouch method with the following:

  ```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
  {
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v;

      for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++)
      {

          View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
          Rect outRect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
          if(outRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
          {
                 /* Write code here to maintain all three buttons toched state, and if all bottons state are present generate Toast.              
          }
      }
  }
  ```

So, for the above code to work, do this in onCreate,

```
onCreate(Bundle..){
b1.setOnTouchListener(this);
b2.setOnTouchListener(this);
b3.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Then whenever buttons are touched, onTouch() will be overriden, now write your logic to maintain the touch, and remember to clear the state within some time so that user can not proceed on just touching 3 button if 1st and 2nd button states are already present.

After that if all buttons states are available (**that means user slided in such a way that all buttons were touched**) so you can generate toast.

> Feel free to ask if you have any doubt in suggested approach

Comment: When I touch a button give me an error out of the application.I can not touch the three buttons I can touch one button.I want to touch the three one touch buttons